# Fullpage.js will not allow me to show a footer

Tags: css, magento, fullpage.js

None of the question on here actually fit what i am seeing, so I am asking this here.

I am using `fullpage.js` with **Magento** for a simple CMS page. The basic structure is quite simple :

**HEADER**
`Fullpage.js` stuff and divs
Div with a footer in it

The header is happy - it stick around. The footer is there - but if I scroll down to it, `fullpage.js` takes over and scrolls me right back up to the last section.

I can't figure out how to make that not happen...

Comment: Have you looked at [the example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html) or the [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections) about it? 
It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve].